# Separating a list of (X,Y)

Tags: python, list, zip, biopython

I am parsing PDB files and I have a list of chain names along with XYZ coordinates in the format (chain,[coordinate]). I have many coordinates, but only 3 different chains. I would like to condense all of the coordinates from the same chain to be in one list so that i get chain = [coordinate], [coordinate],[coordinate] and so on. I looked at the biopython documentation, but I had a hard time understanding exactly how to get the coordinates I wanted, so I decided to extract the coordinates manually. This is the code I have so far:

```
pdb_file = open('1adq.pdb')
import numpy as np

chainids = []
chainpos= []

for line in pdb_file:
    if line.startswith("ATOM"):
        # get x, y, z coordinates for Cas
        chainid =str((line[20:22].strip()))
        atomid = str((line[16:20].strip()))
        pdbresn= int(line[23:26].strip())
        x = float(line[30:38].strip())
        y = float(line[38:46].strip())
        z = float(line[46:54].strip())
        if line[12:16].strip() == "CA":
            chainpos.append((chainid,[x, y, z]))
            chainids.append(chainid)

allchainids = np.unique(chainids)
print(chainpos)
```

and some output:

```
[('A', [1.719, -25.217, 8.694]), ('A', [2.934, -21.997, 7.084]), ('A', [5.35, -19.779,     8.986])
```

My ideal output would be:

```
A = ([1.719, -25.217, 8.694]), ([2.934, -21.997, 7.084]),(5.35, -19.779,8.986])...
```

Thanks!

```
Here is a section of PDB file:
ATOM      1  N   PRO A 238       1.285 -26.367   7.882  0.00 25.30           N  
ATOM      2  CA  PRO A 238       1.719 -25.217   8.694  0.00 25.30           C  
ATOM      3  C   PRO A 238       2.599 -24.279   7.885  0.00 25.30           C  
ATOM      4  O   PRO A 238       3.573 -24.716   7.275  0.00 25.30           O  
ATOM      5  CB  PRO A 238       2.469 -25.791   9.881  0.00 25.30           C
```

A is the chain name there in column 4. I do not know what the chain name is a priori but since I am parsing line by line, I am sticking the chain name with the coordinates in the format I mentioned earlier. Now I would like to pull all of the coordinates with an "A" before them and stick them in one list called "A". I can't just hard code in an "A" because it is not always "A". I also have "L" and "H", but I think I can get them once I get over the hump of understanding..

Comment: Are you trying to create the variable `A`, or print out "A = ([1.719, -25.217, 8.694]), ([2.934, -21.997, 7.084]),(5.35, -19.779,8.986])…"?

Comment: Also, please post a representative sample of the relevant section of the PDB file so that we know what you're trying to parse

Comment: there is an intensive library called pdb_tools, written on Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a list of tuple

```
>>> chainpos.append((chainid,x, y, z))
>>> chainpos 
[('A', 1.719, -25.217, 8.694), ('A', 2.934, -21.997, 7.084)]
>>> import itertools
>>> for id, coor in itertools.groupby(chainpos,lambda x:x[0]):
...     print(id, [c[1:] for c in coor])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I like that it maintains order, because it may become important at some point in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to save them into their own lists using this itertool?

Comment: just change this line and append it into a newlist.            print(id, [c[1:] for c in coor][0]). is it what you want

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like:

```
import numpy as np

chain_dict = {}

for line in open('input'):
    if line.startswith("ATOM"):
        line = line.split()
        # get x, y, z coordinates for Cas
        chainid = line[4]
        atomid = line[2]
        pdbresn= line[5]
        xyz = [line[6],line[7],line[8]]
        if chainid not in chain_dict:
            chain_dict[chainid]=[xyz]
        else:
            chain_dict[chainid].append(xyz)
```

which, for your example data, gives:

```
>>> chain_dict
{'A': [['1.285', '-26.367', '7.882'], ['1.719', '-25.217', '8.694'], ['2.599', '-24.279', '7.885'], ['3.573', '-24.716', '7.275'], ['2.469', '-25.791', '9.881']]
```

and since it's a dictionary, obviously you can do:

```
>>> chain_dict['A']
[['1.285', '-26.367', '7.882'], ['1.719', '-25.217', '8.694'], ['2.599', '-24.279', '7.885'], ['3.573', '-24.716', '7.275'], ['2.469', '-25.791', '9.881']]
```

to get just the xyz coords of the chain you're interested in.

Comment: This looks interesting. I will have to take a little bit to understand the python dictionary.. they are trickier than lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> print chainpos 
[('A', [1.719, -25.217, 8.694]), ('A', [2.934, -21.997, 7.084]), ('A', [5.35, -19.779,     8.986])]
>>> print "A =", [ t[1] for t in chainpos]
```

Comment: What if it's not `'A'`? It's unclear whether we would know what that letter is, a priori

Comment: A is just to symbolize the peptide chain that the atom is a part of, in this case it's a proline.  So in general `A` is not guaranteed.

Comment: Exactly right Seth. In PDB files, chains are always listed contiguously, that is that once there is a letter to represent the chain, that chain letter is kept until the next chain is started. In this case it would go something like:
    A
    A
    A
    A
    L
    L
    H
    H

In my code I stored all of the chain names in allchainids, so it has "['A' 'L' 'H'] in it. The